# Smart Card Running But Getting An Exception

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, windows-services

I am making a windows service using .NET C#. This service uses a class that requires **Smart Card Service** to be running. I executed this service but when running my app I get the following: `Smart card Service is not running or was shutdown. Start the Smart card service in Windows. Error code: 2148532253'`.

What might be the problem? Thanks.

This is where the exception being thrown:

```
PACMAN pacman = new PACMAN(); // this is the object that will be used to read data from the card
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide some code in terms of how you're trying to access / use the Smart card Service and where the exception is being thrown please?

Comment: Looking at: http://www.ecole.ensicaen.fr/~vernois/wsct/WSCT-Core/html/4a738551-3de5-f85a-cf94-7e01e29d75fd.htm the error code: `2148532253` does relate to the `The Smart card resource manager is not running.` Can you send a screenshot of your `Services.msc` window showing that the `Smart Card` Windows Service is running please?

Comment: @ConnorTJ I added the image and the line of code where the exception occurs

Comment: Can you start the `Smart Card Device Enumeration` Service too please as you need both running

Comment: @ConnorTJ did like what u said but still getting the error

Comment: So the `Smart Card` & `Smart Card Device Enumeration Service` Services are both running properly? 

Can you provide the code within your Constructor for the `PACMAN` class please? As you are saying this is where the Exception is being thrown?

Comment: @ConnorTJ actually this is a library I am using (provided by the client) not something I wrote

Comment: Ahh, okay, the only other thing I can think of is to check that the Windows Service and Drivers you have for the Smart Card are all up to date and matching, as some of the "`API`" endpoints (loose term) might have changed within the different versions. I also found this link which may be of some use: 

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/smart-card-receiving-error-resource-manager-not/8630ebca-3d3e-4897-b8d5-1eeede079df4

Comment: @ConnorTJ I have a question, do I have to connect a card reader to my pc to solve this exception? I don't think that this is related but I had to make sure.

Comment: Unfortunately Sam, I wouldn't know as I don't have a Smart Card and haven't used the Smart Card Service before, I would say to give it a go and see if your outcome changes, the error message seems to be related to the actual Windows Service, but I don't know if it's a generic error message sadly, sorry!

Comment: @ConnorTJ no problem, thank u for u generous help

Comment: No worries, sorry I couldn't be of more help/resolve the issue, did you check the drivers and the Windows Service version in relation to the `PACMAN` requirements that you was given by the client? Hopefully they might highlight a mismatch between the 2 and that might help resolve the issue

Comment: Also, I've seen some suggestions that you need to set the `Smart Card` Service and `Smart Card Device Enumeration Service` needs to be set to `Automatic` and both be running, maybe stopping and restarting both could help also

Comment: @ConnorTJ I tried but nothing helped. Plus there is something weird happening after 2 mins these services are being stopped automatically

Comment: Is there anything in your Event Viewer for the Services? Sounds like they are encountering an issue and crashing / stopping.

Comment: @ConnorTJ There are some warning when running these services but not errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237602/discussion-between-connortj-and-sam).

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the problem was because there was no Card Reader attached to my laptop. Weird the exception is so general and not helpful at all!